# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057 return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I built a docker image from a dockerfile.  The dockerfile base is ubuntu and my application is a nodejs application.  The image seems to work fine but after I do a docker run to build my container I get the error below, any thoughts?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057

  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

                 ^



Error: libnode.so.64: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/dist/index.js:60:16)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I have tried uninstalling node_modules and then reinstalling via the env.sh.  I was also trying to see if there was a possible node conflict during installation but I was sure exactly what to check and how to check within my image since I couldn't build the container yet.  Lastly, I wanted to make a directory that was in the error so that it did exist but I wasn't sure what or where to put it. any thoughts?